# Nodejs - support backslash in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, encoding, backslash

I want to keep backslash when I am doing JSON.parse().

I have created a proxy service to hit a third-party service on my microservice application.

API -> **POST <base_url>/api/v1/action**

```
{
  "prop1": "test",
  "config": {
    "username": "testuname",
    "password": "test\f123"
  }
}
```

When I retrieve the password after parsing the JSON, I will be changed from `test\f123` to `test123`. That third-party product is supporting backslash in their password. So, one of the customer had used backslash.

Is there a way to stop removing this backslash in nodejs?

Comment: The JSON is malformed. The backslash should have been escaped ```test\\f123```

Comment: No, with \f(wth all escape sequence) it works. But need to support it as it is. Is there a way?

Comment: Whatever generated the JSON needs fixing to escape the slash. Otherwise you are going to have to detect escaped characters and replace them with the appropriate characters.